# I want to use Key Listener to listen for when I press enter in a JTextArea, but it isn't working

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener

I made a JTextArea with a new Key Listener with this line in my class SetUp:

startWin is from my Window class, and text is the JTextArea object in that class

StrToInt is a method that converts a string to an int without using the parse methods

```
        startWin.text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        int s;
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            start = setup.StrToInt(startWin.text.getText()); //start is static
        }

        }
    });
    s = start;
    return s;
```

My goal was to input a value in text, and press enter to return it and store it to start.

Yet when I do this:

```
public void Maze(Window w) {
    int start = 0;

    w = setup.StartWindow(w);
    while (start == 0) {
        start = setup.Start(w);
    }
}
```

I get a runtime error. What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: What is the error? Also, what is the type of setup?

Comment: Why using a `JTextArea` if the user is not allowed to press enter ? If you only expect a single line input, use a `JTextField`. In that case, you can attach an `ActionListener` to it, which will be triggered when pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

I looked and saw one problem with your "int s;" (was outside of method before)

```
  int s;
  startWin.text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        start = setup.StrToInt(startWin.text.getText()); //start is static
        s = start;
    }

    }
});
  return s;
```